# PowerPC: integer division does not generate SIGFPE

Tags: signals, powerpc, qnx, divide-by-zero, sigfpe

I have Implemented following code in QNX to handle divided by zero exception.

```
static int st_iThreadID = -1;
static sigjmp_buf fpe_env;
float a = -10, b = 0;
volatile float c = 0;
 /**************************************
 *
 * Signal Handler for Divided by zero exception
 *
 ****************************************/
void SignalHandler(int Signo,siginfo_t* info,void* other)
{
 int iThreadID =  gettid();`enter code here`
printf( " exception caught for thread \t %d Generated Signal is \t %d   \n",iThreadID,Signo);   
siglongjmp(fpe_env, info->si_code);
}

 /**************************************
 *
 * Handler Ends
 *
 ****************************************/


int TestDividedByZero()
{
 /*local variable initialization*/
    int l_iStatus = 0;
    sigset_t set;
    int code ;
    struct sigaction act;   /*Sigaction structure to set the action for Signal*/

/*End local variable initialization*/       

    fp_exception_mask(_FP_EXC_DIVZERO, 1 );   /* Set the exception mask for floating point Exception */


    sigfillset( &act.sa_mask);
    sigdelset(&set,SIGFPE);

    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    act.sa_mask = set;
    act.sa_sigaction =SignalHandler;
    sigaction(SIGFPE, &act, NULL ); /* POSIX: Specify the action associated with a signal SIGFPE */


    code = sigsetjmp(fpe_env, 1);
    if(code == 0)
    {

        c = a / b;   /*Here generates floating point signal SIGFPE and registered handler will get call */
        //  printf("value of d is %d \n",d);
    }
    else
    {
        puts( "Jumped from Signal handler");
        c = 0;  // Set result to default value      
    }
    //puts( "End SIGFPE of Testing ");

    return l_iStatus ;
```

}

When the type of variable is float or double , this code generates SIGFPE but when change the variable type to int or long, this code does not generates the SIGFPE. I am using gcc compiler, processor is POWERPC MPC8347 and OS is QNX.
I wants to test SIGFPE with integer value as well.
earlier same code was not generating SIGFPE for float also but later I added fp_exception_mask(), and it is working fine. Is there any such mask for integer operation?

Comment: Does the code crash with a different exception? Its possible on QNX SIGFPE is only raised for floats.

Comment: Other exception works properly.  Is there any compiler option to check if divisor equal to zero before every division operation e.g.   if my code is a = b/c; then compiler should add if(c==0) raise(SIGFPE).